# Serializing List<DayOfWeek> in C#

Tags: c#

I'm trying to create a `JSON` array that contains list of weekdays.

I'm testing this in a console app but it keeps giving me an error i.e. exited with code 0.

Here's what I'm doing:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

var days = new List<DayOfWeek>();
days.Add(DayOfWeek.Monday);
days.Add(DayOfWeek.Wednesday);

var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(days);
Console.WriteLine(json);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Running this code I get a response `[1,3]`. Are you getting any errors or is it just exiting?

Comment: FYI if you're looking to get the strings "Monday" and "Wednesday" then you can do `days.Select(x => x.ToString()).ToList()`.  Or use a `JsonConverter` for the `DayOfWeek` enum.

Comment: The code you've posted [doesn't throw an error](https://dotnetfiddle.net/U4H6Jj). Please [edit] your post with a [mre]. "i.e. exited with code 0" also wouldn't mean an error is thrown by itself.

Comment: @SimonPrice It's exiting with code 0. I was expecting to get `[1,3]` but not getting that.

Comment: An "exit code" is very different than printing to the console. The code you've provided has a 0 exit code _and_ prints `[1,3,]` to STDOUT. If you're getting something different, what did you get, and what code can reproduce that?

Comment: The code in it self works and is fine. Is this a console app or an app of different type?

Comment: Why is it not printing my array then? I also tried `Console.Writeline(json.ToString());` to no avail.

Comment: "Why is it not printing my array then?" It is. https://dotnetfiddle.net/U4H6Jj `json` is a `string`.

Comment: Sorry folks! It's my mistake. It's printing the output. It was scrolling up and I wasn't seeing it. Thank you for your comments!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `System.Text.Json`, as I'm more familiar with it.

You can do what you want with a Linq expression...

```cs
var days = JsonSerializer.Serialize(Enum.GetValues(typeof(DayOfWeek))
  .Cast<DayOfWeek>().ToList());
```

Not actually sure if you need the `Cast<>` in there, but this certainly works.

Comment: "First, use System.Text.Json, as it's more up to date." now _that's_ a hot take!

Comment: Is it? Did I get that wrong? I seem to remember that Microsof introduced that one, and suggested we use it instead of the NewtonSoft one. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: I'm not saying you're wrong, it's your opinion if one is better than the other. I would personally disagree that one is _flat out_ better than the other. AFAIK you're correct on all the technical facts.

Comment: I have no opinion on which is better, not being enough of an expert to say, but was under the impression that it was newer and more up to date. Could be wrong. Either way, that point is irrelevant, it's the bit inside the call to the seraliser that is (hopefully) the answer to the question.

Comment: @gunr2171 Looks like I'm partly right, see [the Microsoft docs on the subject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/migrate-from-newtonsoft?pivots=dotnet-7-0). Looks like `System.Text.Json` is more performant, and will eventually supercede `Newtonsoft.Json`, but doesn't yet support all the features. However, it supports enough that I'd say there is little reason to use the older library out of choice. Thanks for making me look that up though, shows you should always check your assumptions!

Comment: _"as it's more up to date."_ - 1) `Newtonsoft.Json` nuget was updated only 3 days ago =))) 2) If we are talking about using more modern solutions you possibly would want to change `Enum.GetValues(typeof(DayOfWeek)` to `Enum.GetValues<DayOfWeek>()` =)

Comment: @GuruStron Good catch, I removed that comment from my question :). Your suggestion is also good :)

Comment: @AvrohomYisroel I would say that something like "as it is considered a ore modern approach" is also a good wording =)

Comment: @GuruStron Yeah, basically what I meant, but better wording. Anyway, I removed it now, so it's probably not worth debating any more :)

Answer (score -3):

Use NuGet to download the package

"Project" -> "Manage NuGet packages" -> "Search for "newtonsoft json"

Comment: If the program can produce an exit code, that means it's able to be compiled. If it was missing a package and trying to use the package's APIs, it wouldn't compile.